# String count in $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a `$_POST` which contain following data

```
$_POST['survey_que1']
$_POST['survey_que2']
$_POST['survey_que3']
....
```

so on.

I have to get a count of occurrence of `survey_que` from `$_POST`.

Any Ideas please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_POST as $name => $val)
{
    if(strpos($name,'survey_que') !== false && $name != "survey_que")
     $i++;
}
echo "No of times survey_que occured in $_POST[] is ".$i;
```

**EDIT**

@shri in your code if `survey_que2` is not set and `survey_que3` is set then your code fails.
So try this workaround which covers all worst cases also

```
$i=0;
foreach ($_POST as $name => $val)
{
    if(strpos($name,'survey_que') !== false && $name != "survey_que")
    {
     $key=explode("survey_que",$name);
     if(sizeof($key) == 2 && is_numeric($key[1]) && $key[0] == "")
     {
       $i++;
     }
    }
}
echo "No of times survey_que occured in $_POST[] is ".$i;
```

Comment: +1 but you need to decrement i by 1 to show occurence.

Comment: Nope, It takes similar keys also which start with `survey_que`.

Comment: @krishna Thanks for your contribution. I have take care to set a questions in continues order only.

Answer (score 14):

Restructure your data.

```
<input type="text" name="survey_que[]" />
```

This will result in `$_POST['survey_que']` being an array of passed values, which you can easily use `count()` to get the total count.

Comment: Sure. But due to some circumstances i can't do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Serialize $_POST and use "substr_count" for counting ocurrences

```
$how_many = substr_count(serialize($_POST), $search_string));
```

It's the easiest way I find but will count this text even if it's not a $_POST key value

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me exactly i want.

```
$i = 1;
while (isset($_POST['survey_que' . $i])) {
  $i++;
 }

echo $i-1;
```

Thanks everyone for quick support.

Comment: check my edit part which will take only keys like `survey_que1, survey_que2,...`